# SQL Server 2014 Not recognizing 64 bit drivers for Office

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, export

I have a SQL Server 2014 virtual machine. It is a 64 bit version of SQL Server or a 64 bit Windows Server. The SQL Server software was installed before I was hired by the Sysadmin. He choose to have the 32 bit drivers for Access (Office) installed. We’ve talked about it, he claims he did it because we are using a 32 bit version of Office 2010.

Anyway, I uninstalled the AccessRuntime_x32 and installed AccessRuntime_x64. I’ve downloaded both the 2010 and 2013 versions off the Microsoft Website. I’ve restarted SQL Server, I’ve even rebooted the whole server. Yet I still can’t export out more than 64,000 rows of data for Excel nor can I choose a new version of Microsoft Excel past 2007. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When attempting to reproduce your issue, I received the following error:

> the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine

I downloaded the [2007 Office System Driver:  Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)
to resolve the error.  When I choose to export data to Excel and choose a file name of .xls, the export will error at 65,536 rows.  If I choose to export data to Excel and select a file name of .xlsx, the export will complete without error.  This is because in Excel 2010 there is a 1048576 row limit per sheet, and in Excel 97 there is a 65536 row limit per sheet.

Comment: That fixed my problem!   Thank you!  You are full of awesome and win!

Comment: :-) I like being told I'm full of awesome.  You made my day.